# VSTO Powerpoint Identify placeholder in Textbox

Tags: c#, powerpoint, vsto, office-addins

I am creating a PowerPoint Addin with C# VSTO. My strugle at the moment is to identify the date, page number or any other placeholder within the textbox. I can see that textbox value as a plain text which is not good enough. Below is the snipet I am using. Hopefully someone can shed some light on the missing parts.

```
 foreach (Shape shape in slide.Shapes)
        {
            if (shape.HasTextFrame == MsoTriState.msoTrue && shape.TextFrame.HasText == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
            {
                var textRange = shape.TextFrame.TextRange;

                if (shape.Type == MsoShapeType.msoTextBox)
                {

                    var text = textRange.Text; <----- I can see the content as a plain text "Time: 9:00"
                    // How to Find or identify placeholder i.e. 9:00
                                 
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm a VBA guy, but you should be able to check whether the shape Type is a Placeholder, then test the PlaceholderFormat.Type for footers, slide numbers and dates. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-12/ff764209(v=office.12)

Comment: The above code will work if the shape is placeholder. But, if the placeholder is within the TextBox then I cannot identify it as it show as an text. If you have snippet in VBA that would solve the above problem it would be great.

Comment: Ah, I see. There isn't date or slide number field in the object model, I guess MS assumes that the field will always be found in the placeholder. As a workaround, you would have to find the date and date format in use, then find textboxes that are displaying matching text. For the slide number, get the index of the slide and find a text box that displays the same number. It's not foolproof, unfortunately.

Comment: Well, the funny thing is that as a user you always can click inside the textbox and select the placeholder. This means that internally it is not stored as a plain text. I was expecting to see a shape collection within TextBox but this didnt work either.

Comment: The date and slide number are fields, similar to those found in Word. Unfortunately, while Word has a Fields object, PowerPoint does not.